# How to decrease the length between two points OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.1, I am trying to bring down the `(x2,y2)` coordinate in the same angle. For example, the Image below has `Old coordinates` say `P1` and `new coordinated` say `P2`; I am trying to move the `P1` to `P2`.

[image]

I have written the following code for that:

```
import cv2
import math


def new_coordinates(point_one, point_two):
    print(("x1", point_one[0], "y1", point_one[1]), ("x2", point_two[0], "y2", point_two[1]))
    distance = math.sqrt((point_two[0] - point_one[0]) ** 2 + (point_two[1] - point_one[1]) ** 2)
    print("distance between point one and two", distance)

    slope = (point_two[1] - point_one[1]) / (point_two[0] - point_one[0])
    print("Slope", slope)

    angle = math.degrees(math.atan(slope))
    print("angle", angle)

    a = math.cos(angle) * (distance/0.5)
    print("a", a)
    b = math.sin(angle) * (distance/0.5)
    print("b", b)

    x_a = point_one[0] - a
    y_b = point_one[1] - b

    print("New points", (int(x_a), int(y_b)))
    new_distance = math.sqrt((int(x_a) - point_two[0]) ** 2 + (int(y_b) - point_two[1]) ** 2)
    print("new distance", new_distance)
    return int(x_a), int(y_b)

new_co = new_coordinates((400,400), (600,200))

img = cv2.imread('test_images/solidWhiteRight.jpg')
cv2.line(img, (400,400), (600,200), [0,255,0], 7)
cv2.line(img, (400,400), new_co, [204,255,204], 7)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have assumed two coordinates, `A = (400,400)` and `B = (600, 200)` as a reference line, Keeping the point `A` as it is, I tried to moved the point using `new_coordinates` function, but the result is:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Cany someone help me?

Comment: `sin()/cos()` use `radians`, not `degrees`

Comment: @furas Sorry didn't get you. You mean to say I am calculating them in the wrong way

Comment: don't convert angle to degrees - use `math.cos( math.atan(slope) )` - without `math.degrees()`

Comment: and probably you have to use `sin()` to calculate `a`, and `cos()` to calculate `b`

Comment: @furas Ok that worked, but point `B` are on opposite side now.

Comment: Yes! that worked thanks. So to decrease the point `B` value I need to do `a = math.sin(angle) * (distance/5)` and `b = math.cos(angle) * (distance/5)` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but something simpler should work

```
def new_coordinates(point_one, point_two):

    dx = (point_two[0] - point_one[0])
    dy = (point_two[1] - point_one[1])

    x_a = point_one[0] - dx/0.5
    y_b = point_one[1] - dy/0.5

    print("New points", (int(x_a), int(y_b)))

    return (int(x_a), int(y_b))
```

Based on **The intercept theorem**, also known as [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)

---

**EDIT:** in your oryginal version you have to

- skip `math.degrees()` because `sin()`, `cos()` need `radians`
- use `atan2()` instead of `atan()`

Code with simple tests for both functions:

```
import math

def new_coordinates_1(point_one, point_two):

    dx = (point_two[0] - point_one[0])
    dy = (point_two[1] - point_one[1])

    distance = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

    angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)

    a = math.cos(angle) * (distance/0.5)
    b = math.sin(angle) * (distance/0.5)

    x_a = point_one[0] - a
    y_b = point_one[1] - b

    return (round(x_a), round(y_b))

def new_coordinates_2(point_one, point_two):

    '''
    Based on "The intercept theorem", also known as "Thales' theorem"
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem
    '''

    dx = (point_two[0] - point_one[0])
    dy = (point_two[1] - point_one[1])

    x_a = point_one[0] - dx/0.5
    y_b = point_one[1] - dy/0.5

    return (round(x_a), round(y_b))

# --- test ---

data = [
    ((400,400), (600,200)),
    ((400,400), (600,100)),
    ((400,400), (600,400)),
    ((400,400), (400,100)),
    ((400,400), (200,100)),
    ((400,400), (200,500)),
]

for p1, p2 in data:
    print(p1, p2)
    print("#1 New points", new_coordinates_1(p1, p2))
    print("#2 New points", new_coordinates_2(p1, p2))
    print('---')
```

Results:

```
(400, 400) (600, 200)
#1 New points (0, 800)
#2 New points (0, 800)
---
(400, 400) (600, 100)
#1 New points (0, 1000)
#2 New points (0, 1000)
---
(400, 400) (600, 400)
#1 New points (0, 400)
#2 New points (0, 400)
---
(400, 400) (400, 100)
#1 New points (400, 1000)
#2 New points (400, 1000)
---
(400, 400) (200, 100)
#1 New points (800, 1000)
#2 New points (800, 1000)
---
(400, 400) (200, 500)
#1 New points (800, 200)
#2 New points (800, 200)
---
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help!